# How to create a dataframe with three lists?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, numpy

**I would like to add a third list to the dataframe**. I used zip() only for two lists ("List1" & "List2"), but I'm not sure how to add a third list ("List3")?

```
List1 = ['Value1','Value2']
List2 = ['Value3','Value4']
List3 = ['Value5','Value6']


import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(List1, List2)),
                 columns =['Column list1', 'Column list2'])
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `zip` is not limited to two iterables. You can pass however many you'd like, for example:

```py
>>> list(zip([1,2], [3,4], [5,6]))
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

That said, when creating a `DataFrame` with multiple columns it is more customary to use the `dict` argument:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2],
    'b': [3,4],
    'c': [5,6],
})
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

So, in your case, you would probably write:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column list1': List1,
    'Column list2': List2,
    'Column list3': List3,
})
```

**Edit** (to reflect the newly formulated question):

If you have your `df` with just the two first lists, and want to add the 3rd after the fact:

```py
df['Column list3'] = List3
```

Comment: what if the list values are different every time? how can I create the dataframe only with the names of the lists? without having the lists themselves(their values)? @Pierre D

Comment: I have 3 lists with two values each. but I don't know what those values are. So how can I set up the dataframe only with the list names (List1, List2, List3)?

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by "every time"?  A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) doesn't have to be so terse that nobody can understand what the problem to solve is...  It should be complete enough to clearly indicate the problem you are facing.